# How to make a map return a class that extends an abstract class?

Tags: typescript, oop

I have this code.

```
abstract class Parent{

    constructor(){
        console.log("New class created")
    }
}

class Child1 extends Parent{}

class Child2 extends Parent{}


export const classes = new Map<number, Parent>([
    [1, Child1],
    [2, Child2]
])
```

When I `get()` a class from the classes Map i cant initialize a new instance of that class by using the `new` keyword  (error is thrown) like this:

```
let _class = ClassMap.classes.get(1)
let classInstance = new _class()
```

How can I implement such functionality ?

Comment: Did you try to add `constructor(){}` to the parent class?

Comment: @Drag13 yes the constructor is there. I tried to omit the actual implementation of the classes to make it easily readable. Ill add the contructor to make things more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
export const classes = new Map<number, {new(): Parent}>([
    [1, Child1],
    [2, Child2]
])
```

Comment: what would it look like when the constructor takes in a number parameter ? 

`export const classes = new Map<number, {new(num:number): Parent}>([
    [1, Child1],
    [2, Child2]
])`
When doing `let _class = ClassMap.classes.get(1)
let classInstance = new _class(10)`
I get an error

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAQwRgzgLgTiDGUAE8A2IISQBRDApgHZQDewwSlKA9odDAK6LUwAUhDAtgFxIedh8MAJRkq4mnWqp8AOlTUA5qwBEAOXwB3FOkwoCIKPgAmK4RSoBfYNeBoMWAMIALAJapjARiT4AHkcJjLFwCYhJbez0Xd2MAJh9-IiCcPCJSWz8ABxZkeFpoHQd8LABePi0kAFkQTIAefkEYABokEkItdi5eBqFhXhC0ywA+VgBtC0pRzxboj08AXSaJpFHYmbcPWPngefNyGWQAfUjSwsxi2UV8KFZPc1cAMyRWY90IYVblg7OIAEk6KAgQjwfBIMrtbSvBysADMsXM1iAA

Comment: If that solved your problem it will be greatly appreciated if you could mark my answer as correct, to help other people who seek an answer. If it does not yet solve your question, I will gladly try to help.